# How to apply texture on old particle system converted to hair curves with Geometry Nodes

Tags: uv, bezier-curves, hair, texture-coordinates, unreal-engine

I'm new to Geometry Nodes

I created a tiger fur with the old Particle System, then converted it in curves, exported the groom mesh in Alembic file and Unreal Engine imported it well, but the root UV is generated badly, the texture map seems messy on the fur.

So I thought the best way is to use the new Hair Curves of the 3.5, so I could create data like radius, color, suface_uv_coordinate. Then export this with the addon Groom Exporter. Unreal Engine imported the abc with the color and radius data but not the Root Uv, then I kept trying fix the issue.

But I keep having this issue with my curves : Invalid surface UVs on X Curves.

I'm struggling between two questions:

- How could I transfer texture on groom, made with old particule system then converted?
- Why curves keep getting invalid Uvs (Uvs islands aren't overlapping)

I applied a material on the converted hair curves, created a link between it and the data created with Geometry Nodes, but I'm sure that I'm using the wrong node setup

Every way to proceed has been tried, I'm lost.

[image]

[image]